# Multilabel Classification using random forest

Tags: nlp, random-forest, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I have 5 labels and 499 datasets.

I tried using random forest classier. I have two inputs for the model: output of tfidf and review_length.

```
train_tfIdf = vectorizer_tfidf.fit_transform(X_train.values.astype('U'))
x_train=['train_tfIdf',question['review_len']]
```

this is the error that is displayed when I execute:

```
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'train_tfIdf'
```

Comment: [reprex] please, with minimal input data as text until the line that produces your error

Comment: As a side note, try `x_train=[train_tfIdf,question['review_len']]`, without quotes, and see if this helps